# Implementing product group besides Category in Magento

Tags: php, magento, categories

I am developing a shop in Magento, I got a situation 
For example I have main category as

Furniture

and inside this category I have lots of other categories but two of them are

- Wooden Chairs
- Metal Chairs

and there are products in both of them.

But I want to see groups on my site, say Chairs , and when a user browse Chairs page, he will see all the chairs regardless of whether it is wooden or Metal.

I don't want user to see Chairs as category, in category they will see Wooden chairs and Metal Chairs, but in group they will see Chairs.

What is the best way to achieve such division.

Comment: Why aren't you wanting to use a Category? Need to know, as I might have a solution but it does use Categories

Comment: But I have more specific categories already like wooden chairs, and Metal chairs, I don't want to show it like Furniture->chairs->wooden chairs. I want to show mix-up products from multiple categories in group. another example, the group can be electronics but categories can be Computer, TV, DVD Player etc.

Comment: Thats what you use attribute sets, attributes and layered navigation filters

Comment: @jprofitt , using is category is fine too, as long as they are not visible on front-end. I have a thought, if I have two main catgories like visible-categories(sub-categories will show in header as main categories) and another category called "groups" not visible with normal categories, but products like all chairs will also be added to Chair group besides the normal categories.

Comment: Yeah that was actually the route I was going to suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a thought, if I have two main catgories like visible-categories(sub-categories will show in header as main categories) and another category called "groups" not visible with normal categories, but products like all chairs will also be added to Chair group besides the normal categories.

Thanx to @jprofitt.